# How to make parallax scrolling to multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make parallax effect to multiple columns that contains photos.

I tried lots of ideas but i did not find a solution to make something like this http://weareeli.dk/ from scratch.

Can you help me please with some ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, checkout this amazing library: http://scrollmagic.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, this is not a parralax scrolling. That would mean that things will scroll in different speeds making the appearance of being farther away from the eye.

What we have here (I guess) is even simpler.

- Every column is separate from each other
- The whole is `overflow hidden`
- Every column has two `EventListeners`

  1. The first being a drag listener on the dark grey band with the title
  2. The second is a scroll listener on the column itself
- Whenever an event of the former two is catched, there is a controller action called, which will calculate a percentage value between 0% and 100% (or 0 and 1)
- That controller will send a message to the view with that calculated percentage value
- The view will call functions (could be done with jQuery) which will scroll the column and move the grey band up or down.

That should be all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If you have a little time can you help me please to see what is wrong here? [https://jsfiddle.net/georgeSohan/u849yzn3/13/] - I make a finddle. All I try is to make the columns to react at event like in the page that I show in the post and to scroll [http://weareeli.dk/]. Thank you very much

Comment: It's https://jsfiddle.net/georgeSohan/u849yzn3/13/ the closing `]` was interpreted as part of the url

Comment: Thank you very much! You made my day!